# HTTPS forwarding for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, subdomain, forwarding

I have a domain, let's make it `example.com`, and a subdomain, `sub.example.com`. For the subdomain I have a SSL certificate, for the main domain I don't. On my server I have a `.htaccess` file for my main domain, but none for my subdomain. How do I specify, in this file, to forward from `http://sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com`? Or do I need a second `.htaccess` file in the folder for my subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your subdomain is hosted in a subdirectory off the main domain's document root? So the main domain's `.htaccess` file is in the parent directory? (If not, then you will need another `.htaccess` file in the root of the subdomain.)

Try the following mod_rewrite directives at the top of the main domain's `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to 301 only when you are sure it's working OK. (Permanent redirects are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

You only need one `RewriteEngine` directive at the top of your file.

**UPDATE:** If the file structure is as mentioned above (ie. the subdomain is located in a subdirectory off the main domain's document root - where the `.htaccess` file is located) then you will need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable to reference the URL-path, not a backreference (ie. `$1` - as I had initially) to the captured `RewriteRule` *pattern*, since the captured backreference will contain the *subdirectory*, which is not part of the URL-path.

Comment: Curious that you would _unaccept_ the answer 3 years later - without comment? (Did it work initially?!) Anyway, I see there was an issue with my answer, which I've now updated/corrected... when accessing the subdomain (that is assumed to point to a subdirectory off the main domain's document root) then you will need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, not a backreference (`$1`) to the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ as I had initially.